# Unable to access endpoints in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am new to Kubernetes. when I run the command "minikube kubectl -- get endpoints" then it is showing endpoints. when I hit these endpoint in browser then this is not showing anything and saying can't reach this page.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I tried to access endpoints but unable to access these endpoints in browser

Comment: Can you mention how you created this endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing the endpoints from cluster using curl command as follows

```bash
    $ curl endpoint-url:port
```

OR

```bash
    $ curl http://endpoint-url:port
```

If you want to access the endpoints through your localhost browser then you need to start the `minikube tunnel`. This minikube tunnel sets up the network tunnel between the host and Minkube VM. To start this process follow the below steps

- Start your minikube by running the `$ minikube start` in your
  terminal.
- Run the `$ minikube tunnel` command in the terminal to start the network tunnel.
- This command will give you output something like status 1/1 the tunnel has been successfully established. Don't stop the command by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Let this run as it is so the tunnel will be running in the background.
- Now you can access the endpoints of the kubernetes cluster using your localhost url. For example your service running on a port `8081` then you can access it in the browser by `http://localhost:8081`

**Note:** You can try accessing the minikube nodeport services with `$ minikube service service-name`. In this case minikube tunnel does not required.

Refere to these offical documents [DOC1](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) [DOC2](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/) for more detailed information and usage.

Comment: Hi @Akash did you get a chance to check the answer? is it helpful?